# Best clustering approach when variable combination sizes vary

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, data-visualization

Let's say my dataset is as follows:

```
            Score    Skills
Student 1    56      problem solving, communication
Student 2    34      communication
Student 3    92      critical thinking, problem solving
........
```

where the data set contains 1000 students, their score (out of 100) and relevant skills (from a set of known 50 skills).

What would be the best approach to identify relationships between score and skills? For example I would like to know which skills (or combinations of skills) tend to result in a higher/lower score. I'm confused as to which clustering approach is suitable as each student will have a different combination of skills which is not equal in size to others.

Comment: Why are you asking specifically about clustering when you want to "identify relationships" (pattern of association)?

Comment: thank you for your reply, I thought clustering would be an appropriate way to look at the relationships, but other ideas are welcome.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with clustering. For exploratory purposes, try looking at boxplots or histograms by skill type. If you need to test if the skills differ, you want an ANOVA, or a nonparametric variant.